# VB.NET get a specific "href" by id

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, html-agility-pack

I need help to get start with my app.

I try to get HREF link from webpage without webbrowser.

I use HtmlAgilityPack but i cant get the spefic HREF:

```
<a id="ItemsList_file_0" title="HR9nqJCIqHex8niygKtwUHpdkjRGNaH22Oy54SPBmw.avi" href="http://dsa11.uverload.com/d/a012284e-1fd5-4317-82d3-9bf9e738f0a2/BIfmZ/0lOipBI/HR9nqJCIqHex8niygKtwUHpdkjRGNaH22Oy54SPBmw.avi" target="_blank">HR9nqJCIqHex8niygK..22Oy54SPBmw.avi</a><br />
```

i try this code .

```
Dim webreq As System.Net.HttpWebRequest = System.Net.HttpWebRequest.Create("http://www.uverload.com/view/0lOipBI")
Dim webres As System.Net.HttpWebResponse = webreq.GetResponse
Dim sr As System.IO.StreamReader = New System.IO.StreamReader(webres.GetResponseStream)
Dim docStr As String = sr.ReadToEnd
Dim HAPdoc As New HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument

HAPdoc.LoadHtml(docStr)

Dim HAPnode As HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNode
HAPnode = HAPdoc.GetElementbyId("ItemsList_file_0")
MsgBox(HAPnode.InnerText)
```

End Sub

give me nothing

Comment: Why cant you? What happens? How are you attempting to do so?

Comment: any one? its possible?

Comment: `href` is an attribute. Try `HAPnode.Attributes["href"].Value`

Comment: :\ theB its not help

Comment: what is the url you are trying to scrape ?

Comment: i try to get href link from http://www.fileflyer.com/view/0lOipBI in "id" ItemsList_file_0 but if you dont havr a password u can not see the herf... i have so i post the code from html see up